# An example of a continuous function that does not always map open subsets of the domain to open subsets of the range.

Tags: real-analysis

I have interested in understanding what this means. I don't particularly understand what it means to have open subsets of the domain to open subsets of the range. I am thinking that if the domain is (1,10) then it could map to like (2,40) or something...? I am unsure what exactly this means or why it is relevant for continuous functions.

If there's any function that comes in mind that I could reference to understand this, that would be very cool! Thank you.

Comment: A constant function?

Comment: Did you mean range, or co-domain?

Comment: range @DavidPeterson

Comment: What about $f(x)=x^3-x$? It's continuous, and $\mathbb R$ is the domain and range. What is the image of the open set $(0,1)$?

Comment: under a continuous function, the inverse image of an open set in the codomain is always an open set in the domain; on the other hand, an open map is a function  that maps open sets to open sets